# How do statisticians defend their model when they don't omit outliers?

Tags: outliers, qq-plot

There are many posts on this site where people argue in favor of **not** omitting outliers. That seems to be the general sentiment, and many good arguments are presented.

However, *because they are outliers*, including them in your model is likely to severely break model assumptions.

So, how do you then defend your model, after you've made the decision to not omit outliers?

In my personal case, I have many outliers. They're still outliers relatively speaking, since my data is huge, but there are many of them. Here's what they do to my qq plot:

[image]

So, say that you include outliers in your data. How do you defend that decision, given model diagnostic plots as above? How can you possibly use your model to anything, when it's clearly not a good fit?

Of course you could go out searching for a better model that fits your entire data, but assume for discussion's sake that you can't find such a model.

Comment: This isn't a question about outliers.  By definition, outliers are *rare*. It's a question about model mis-specification.

Comment: @whuber is correct. More specifically the issue is that of non-normal data. These are not outliers.

Comment: I'd say you change your model; either fit a version of your current model that is robust or resistant to the outliers, or fit a model that more closely represents that data generating process for the response. The latter seems most relevant to the data/model behind the QQ plot you show

Answer (score 1):

The comments by whuber addresses your particular case: These are not outliers.

But your title question is more general and your text raises several issues. There certainly are cases with outliers.

You write

> However, because they are outliers, including them in your model is
> likely to severely break model assumptions.

Not necessarily. Yes, they will likely (but not necessarily) break the assumptions for OLS regression. But there are other models. Closest to OLS are probably robust regression (several types) and quantile regression. But there are also tree models, forest models and so on.

> How can you possibly use your model to anything, when it's clearly
> not a good fit?

Quite aside from the whole question of outliers, sometimes you don't have a good fit. In the social sciences and many other fields, relationships are often very messy and have poor fits. But they may be better than nothing.

> Of course you could go out searching for a better model that fits your
> entire data, but assume for discussion's sake that you can't find such
> a model.

Well, can you give an example where this happens? There are a lot of models and some of them make very few assumptions. Even if your DV is multimodal, I think you could use quantile regreession.

But, if there is such a case then a good data analyst will say "sorry, nothing works here."

Answer (score 0):

With the data I work with, extreme right skew is the norm, both in the features and the outcomes. I also have so much data to work with that I'm only using a small subsample of all the data available to me.

For outcomes, I usually end up changing a continuous outcome to a binary one: if most of the values are in the range [0, 10] but 1% are >1000, I think the very first question you should ask of your data is "what separates the typical values from the extremely high values?". Note that depending on what you're interested in, you may end up fitting multiple models, one for the outliers and one for the typical values.

For features, I often do something similar: a binary value for x > 25th percentile, 50th, 75th, 95th, etc. I typically have a lot of data so those bins are big. Alternatively, we can use splines but the results are bit harder to interpret and with really heavy skew, you need to be super careful about the placement of knots.

One thing to note is that in this case, I'm allowing leakage. However, since the amount of data I work with is quite large, the amount of leakage isn't too bad *and* I can always fix the points and resample since I'm always using a sample of my data anyways.